# Как заполнить cell?

Tags: objective-c

Мне нужно заполнить один Cell но тремя разными настройками, как это можно сделать чтоб постоянно не создавать новые Cell для разных классов?

Comment: А покажите ,что у вас сейчас есть? Хотя бы частично решили задачу?

Comment: @Nick

нет, пока не решил, я хотел для каждого класса делать отдельный cell, но они все будут одинаковыми только текст разный, мне сказали что так лучше не делать, и посоветовали реализовать это через property, пока не могу найти ничего похожего, и понятия не имею как это сделать

Comment: Можно больше информации? что за настройки? заполнить один cell тремя имеется ввиду тремя вместе или использовать один и тот же cell для трех разных случаев?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете заполнить свой прототип ячейки различными данными в методе dataSource таблицы: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Если ячейка стандартная, то например заполнить Title ячейки можно использовав проперти ячейки: `cell.textLabel.text`